# One column two function, and transfer data to next sheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

How to add data to Template column (from) if Transaction column O value is **"From"**, and if Transaction column O value is **"To"** then it will separate to Template column (To)

Please help, i not sure how the code program. Hope can help me some. Thank you

```
Sheets("Transaction").Select
If Cells(lr, 17).Value = "From" Then
    Range(Cells(2, 18), Cells(lr, 18)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Set X = Selection
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Range("D8").Select
    X.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End If

Sheets("Transaction").Select
If Cells(lr, 17).Value = "To" Then
    Range(Cells(2, 18), Cells(lr, 18)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Set X = Selection
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Range("F8").Select
    X.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End If
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88HkP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAiuL.png)

Comment: Cannot be both "From" and "To" at the same time, so did you mean OR?

Comment: So cannot at the same time, i should give 2 columns?

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the rows in sheet Transaction and fill in sheet Template? Can you also show the part you assign `lr` value? And how do you determine which row to fill in in sheet Template?

Comment: My `lr` is `lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying values from sheet Transaction to different columns but the same row in sheet Template, you can do something like below

```
    If Sheets("Transaction").Cells(lr, 17).Value = "From" Then
        Sheets("Template").Cells(lr, 4) = Sheets("Transaction").Cells(lr, 18).Value
    End If
    
    If Sheets("Transaction").Cells(lr, 17).Value = "To" Then
        Sheets("Template").Cells(lr, 6) = Sheets("Transaction").Cells(lr, 18).Value
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Criteria Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransferTransactions()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Transaction")
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    
    Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp)
    
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Range("Q1", slCell) ' has headers
    Dim svrg As Range ' no headers
    Set svrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns("R").Resize(slrg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    Dim sCriteria As Variant: sCriteria = Array("From", "To")
    Dim dAddresses As Variant: dAddresses = Array("D8", "F8")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Template")
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria)
        slrg.AutoFilter 1, Criteria(n)
        On Error Resume Next
            Set srg = svrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
            Set dfCell = dws.Range(dAddresses(n))
            srg.Copy
            dfCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Set srg = Nothing
        End If
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next n

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Goto dws.Range("A1"), True
    
    MsgBox "Transactions transferred to the template.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: It can work but Range D8 & F8 didn't fill in

Answer (score 0):

I have filter the Name so just copy the same name and same number data to other sheet

[image]

Comment: Thanks all, this question was solved already~